# Cropping Core Image issues

Tags: objective-c, opengl, crop, core-image

I'm using OpenGL to draw image to screen. Due to zoom ability my image sometimes gets translated through z-axis. And user, for example, has image with size 3200x2000, he zooms it out because it doesn't fits the screen. And after zooming out he wants to crop part of image. I register selection rectangle. Then use bottom left corner coordinates and distance between top right corner and bottom left corner. Coordinates are used like that:

```
//I get one coordinate from mouse down, and then last point from moueDragged events. 
float firstx = mouseDownFirst.x * (zoomSlider.floatValue * (-10));
float firsty = mouseDownFirst.y * (zoomSlider.floatValue * (-10));
float lastx = mouseDragLast.x * (zoomSlider.floatValue * (-10));
float lasty = mouseDragLast.y * (zoomSlider.floatValue * (-10));

//Then I draw selection rectangle to screen.
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(firstx, firsty);
glVertex2f(firstx, lasty);
glVertex2f(lastx, lasty);
glVertex2f(lastx, firsty);
glEnd();
glFlush();

//and do crop. Because image is drawn to framebuffer, I will read frame buffer info and make image from it. Coordinates are being translated back to normal
firstx = firstx / (zoomSlider.floatValue * (-10));
firsty = firsty / (zoomSlider.floatValue * (-10))
lastx = lastx / (zoomSlider.floatValue * (-10));
lasty = lasty / (zoomSlider.floatValue * (-10));


glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, framebuffer);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [tempRep bitmapData]);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

CIImage *firstImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep:tempRep];

//cropping image to rect and getting result image
float distanceWidth = lastx - firstx;
float distanceHeight = lasty - firsty;

CIImage* secondImage = [firstImage imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(firstx, firsty, distanceWidth, distanceHeight)];

CIFilter* transform = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform"];
NSAffineTransform* affineTransform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[affineTransform translateXBy:-firstx yBy:-firsty];
[transform setValue:affineTransform forKey:@"inputTransform"];
[transform setValue:secondImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
CIImage* lastImage = [transform valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
```

But it returns bad image. Not what I selected. For example:

Selection
[image]

Cropped image
[image]

Comment: Did I understand you right? You display an image in perspective mode and move the quad along the Z axis for zooming? Why not simply scale the quad?

Comment: Because my image comes from 3 layers. 1 layer - background, 2nd layer mask (brush stroke) and 3rd layer - foreground. So when I move everything on z-axis everything is being translated just as I need. So it's simpliest way for me.

Comment: Nothing gets simpler by this, unless you aim for some parallax effect. Zooming is normally implemeted by either applying a scale on the geometry, or by reducing the clipping plane limits of the projection.